# add dynamic view to android tabhost

Tags: android, android-tabhost

How can I add a dynamic view in a `TabHost`.

I have two tabs i.e. `TabA` and `TabB`.  In `TabA`, I have 2 buttons and I want to set the layout (I have 2 different XML layout's) of `TabB`, depending upon the button pressed in `TabA`.

Can anyone help me.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on the implementation of your TabHost. Have you used Activities or Views as Tabs?

Generally in your TabActivity you could use getTabHost().getTabWidget().getChildAt(index) or another method to get the view of a Tab.

If you use Activities as the children, you could also start a new Intent with your ActivityGroup and set a new view within the onCreate() method.

If you have problems finding examples for ActivityGroups with TabHosts, I can provide you a code sample showing you how to do it and also how to change the view within another tab by clicking a button.